# Wordpress function using get_results ARRAY_A response problem

Tags: php, wordpress

thanks for looking at my issue. So I am trying to return each term of the five that my query is selecting. Here is my function:

```
function VD_top_terms(){
global $wpdb;
$VDtermsSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT AN_terms.name from AN_posts INNER JOIN AN_term_relationships on AN_term_relationships.object_id = AN_posts.ID INNER JOIN AN_term_taxonomy on AN_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=AN_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN AN_terms on AN_term_taxonomy.term_id=AN_terms.term_id where AN_posts.post_date_gmt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and AN_term_taxonomy.taxonomy ='post_tag' group by AN_terms.name order by count DESC limit 5";
$VDtResults = $wpdb->get_results($VDtermsSQL, ARRAY_A);
foreach( $VDtResults as $VDsinTerm) {
    echo $VDsinTerm;
}
}
```

This is the response:

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here. If i remove the foreach and echo statement and substitute it for a printr statement I get the following which is why I switched over to the foreach loop and added ARRAY_A.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Cat ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Door ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => School ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => falls ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Court ) )
```

I am trying to get the results Cat, Door, School, Falls, Court to display on the page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to get?

Comment: Updated post. I am trying to get the results to display on the page

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of ARRAY_A use OBJECT. Changed the echo to a print_r statement and defined the column name where the output is.

```
function VD_top_terms(){
global $wpdb;
$VDtermsSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT AN_terms.name from AN_posts INNER JOIN AN_term_relationships on AN_term_relationships.object_id = AN_posts.ID INNER JOIN AN_term_taxonomy on AN_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=AN_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN AN_terms on AN_term_taxonomy.term_id=AN_terms.term_id where AN_posts.post_date_gmt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and AN_term_taxonomy.taxonomy ='post_tag' group by AN_terms.name order by count DESC limit 5";
    $VDtResults = $wpdb->get_results($VDtermsSQL, OBJECT);
    foreach( $VDtResults as $VDsinTerm) {
        print_r($VDsinTerm->name);
    }
    }
```